# Testing as you code on large C projects

Tags: php, c, testing, compilation, development-environment

I've been having a look over the PHP-SRC project, and I've read over the brief development guide at: http://php.net/build-setup.php

However being relatively new to C (but not new to programming), I am a little taken aback by the thought that I need to recompile every time I need to test a change.

When writing in PHP, I can bolt on a small snippet to see if `x == y` at a certain point of execution and test it almost immediately.  But before I start diving in a project as large as PHP, I want to know if I am mistaken in that I would need to build the entirety of the source to test small changes.

Is there a stage in the build process where small changes can be compiled into an existing binary without waiting 10-20 minutes every time?

Comment: That really depends on what you're doing. If you're working on a PHP extension, you can simply build the extension (which generally doesn't take longer than 1~2 minutes) by running `phpize && ./configure --enable-extname && make && make install`. Besides, `make` does keep track of what objects it should recompile, and which ones remained unchanged since last the code was compiled. Also: checking if `x == y` is something you don't do by adding code in C, you do that by using a debugger (like gdb)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I've given it a try, its the core php-src I'm looking into.  Following the instructions the build process was relatively straight forward.  Even after adding some arbitrary code to `zend.h`, although running `make` didn't do anything, running './configure; make' does, and it was pretty quick.  Is this the correct procedure for compiling incremental changes?

Comment: running `./configure; make` seems a bit odd (sure it's not `./configure && make`?), check `./configure --help`, and actually go through all the arguments you want/need to pass to `configure` (like which extensions to compile and which features you want enabled etc...). Then run `make` again

Answer (score 1):

i think make is what you need.
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/
and the documentaion is at 
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html
so you have many large source files, and you made a small change in just one of them, make will only recompile that source file since the others are up to date.
back in the time i built a mini "shell", here is the makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Werror -Wfatal-errors 
OBJECTS=parser.o analyser.o processing.o prompt.o
LINK=-lfl
shell: $(OBJECTS)
        gcc $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LINK) -o shell
parser.o: shell.y 
        bison -d shell.y
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c shell.tab.c -o parser.o
analyser.o: shell.l
        flex shell.l
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c lex.yy.c -o analyser.o
processing.o:processing.c processing.h
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c processing.c -o processing.o
prompt.o: prompt.c prompt.h
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c prompt.c -o prompt.o
clean: 
        rm -f $(OBJECTS) shell.tab.c lex.yy.c shell.tab.h
```

so if i made a change in processing.c, make will only rebuild processing.o and then re-link the project.
so a make file consists of rules :

```
> target : prerequisite

           recipe
```

make needs prerequisite to build target using recipe.
finally, if you want to remove the object files, you can add a "clean" rule and then run :

```
make clean
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question _at all_. PHP already uses make as part of its build procedure, [check the src](https://github.com/php/php-src). OP is wondering if there's an alternative to rebuilding the whole project whenever he changes something and wants to know it it works as expected. Besides: OP links to the build-setup page which ***explicitly*** states you need autotools (which includes automake + autoconf) to build PHP

Comment: Well it looks good, true I know php-src already has "make", but it is good to know it does perform partial compilations.  I don't think it would be a too specific a question if I asked for a typical build process for php-src, since it is a pretty common domain.  If this answer could be modified to detail the steps in developing and testing that project, I would greatly appreciate it, it wouldn't need to be overly expansive, I can always fill in the gaps.